# Undefined control sequence in \documentclass?

Tags: errors

Hello I'm running TexWorks from the MiKTeX & consistently getting this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 \documentclass
                  [prd,12pt,reprint,showkeys,showpacs,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}
?
```

Here is my whole preamble:

```
\documentclass[prd,12pt,reprint,showkeys,showpacs,nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}

%additional macros
\usepackage{amsmath} % for creating subequations
\usepackage{graphicx} % for insterting figures
\usepackage{verbatim} % for including verbatim text
\usepackage{color} % for colored text
\usepackage{subfigure} % for side-by-side figures
\usepackage{hyperref} % for creating hypertext links
```

Comment: Are you compiling with `pdflatex`? The error suggests that you are using `pdftex`; if this is so, change to `pdflatex`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @tohecz 11 seconds ;).

Comment: @cfr My bad. I meant `tex` It's fixed now.

Comment: Okay fixed that. Thank you! Now I'm getting this error:

Comment: initexmf.exe: Windows API error 5: Access is denied.

initexmf.exe: Data: C:\
miktex-pdftex.exe: The operation failed for some reason.
miktex-pdftex.exe: Data: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\initexmf.exe

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a problem with the engine used.